# Get line in file

Tags: tcl

How to get string in line 3 from end line or maximum line [expr max_line - 3], i have write the code below but I cannot get by line 3 from end line or maximum line.

```
set idx 0
while {![eof $flopen]} {
  gets $flopen line
  puts $line
  set vlist [split $line " "]
  set vle [string trim [lindex $vlist 0]]  
  if {$vle == "STP"} {
  set dtxid [string trim [lindex $value_list 1]]
  set dtid [string trim [lindex $value_list 4]]
  gets $flopen line
  gets $flopen line
  gets $flopen line
  set line [join $line ","]
  set tglist($idx) $dtxid
  set gslist($idx) $dtid
  set atblist($idx) $line

  set data_end_from_max_line $datax ;# Can set the string here [expr $max_line - 3]

  incr idx
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing this sort of thing, the easiest approach (provided the data isn't too large, so no more than a couple of hundred megabytes) is to load it all in and process it inside Tcl as a list of lines.

```
set lines [split [read $flopen] "\n"]
set particularLine [lindex $lines end-3]
```

Comment: that`s perfectly but I must reopen the file, isnt right?! I mean that can just one open get by line it?

Comment: Since we're counting backwards from the end of the file, we don't want a spurious empty last element in the list. Better to do `set lines [split [read -nonewline $flopen] \n]`